# Display content based on wether a wishlist is public or private and if there are 0 or more than 0 items in the wishlist

Tags: php, pdo

so users can have a wishlist where they can add items. they can also choose if its public or private.
$wishlistisPublic means that 1 is public and 0 is private.
what i want is to display different messages based on these conditions.
my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oopphp_users INNER JOIN oopphp_wishlist ON oopphp_users.userID = oopphp_wishlist.userID_fk WHERE userID = ? ORDER BY itemID_fk ASC";
$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindColumn('wishlistIsPublic', $wishlistisPublic, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$itemCount = $stmt->rowCount();

if($wishlistisPublic == 1){
            if($itemCount > 0){
                echo "<h1 class='w-100'>There are {$itemCount} items on this users wishlist</h1>";
                return $results;
            } else {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>No items in wishlist</div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>This user has set their wishlist to private.</div>";
        }
}
```

so first of all if it is public, and there are more than 0 items in the wishlist, then i display it. this works

if the wishlist is private it will say that its private. this works.

where the problem arises is when im checking wether or not there are more than 0 items, refering to my $itemCount variable.

if there are more than 0 it will display them. if there are 0 i want to say its empty. however if the wishlist is public and the $itemCount is 0 it will not display that else statement. it say that the wishlist is private.

so i never get this to show:

```
else {
 echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>No items in wishlist</div>";
}
```

Comment: You would be better off using `$itemCount = count($results);`

Comment: i tried with count() but it has the exact some results @NigelRen

Comment: basically what are you doing here is all wrong. you cannot fetch an array with all rows and at the same time just a a single column from a single row separately. you should stick with fetchAll and then get all the information from it.

Comment: can a user have both private and public items in their wishlist? to which table the column wishlistIsPublic belongs?

Comment: the WHOLE wishlist is either public or private. the "wishlistIsPublic" belongs to the user table. the table with wishlist is a separate table.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does `$wishlistIsPublic` contain?

Comment: $wishlistIsPublic is either 1 or 0, so 1 for true(the wishlist is public) or 0 for false(the wishlist is private). @NicoHaase

Comment: @hndvf how did you debug that? By using Xdebug or dumping it after having it read?

Comment: i tried doing a print_r() with $wishlistIsPublic and $itemCount(). basically, if the wishlist was private then it was null and not 0 as i expected, so it ignored the condition since it was not met. since the condition was ignored, i got an error. but it is fixed now. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a JOIN to display this information.

In case of INNER JOIN there will be no information on whether a wishlist is public or private when there are no items.
In case of LEFT LEFT there will be a false positive row in results when there are no items.

Hence you have to run two queries

```
$sql = "SELECT wishlistIsPublic FROM oopphp_users WHERE userID = ?";
$stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$userID]);
$wishlistisPublic = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM oopphp_wishlist WHERE userID_fk = ? ORDER BY itemID_fk ASC";
$stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$userID]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();


if($wishlistisPublic) {
    if($results) {
        echo "<h1 class='w-100'>There are {$itemCount} items on this users wishlist</h1>";
        foreach ($results as $row) {
             // display results
        }
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>No items in wishlist</div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>This user has set their wishlist to private.</div>";
}
```

Note that you should **never ever** call connect() more than **once**. A single connection must be made only once and then used to perform all queries in the script

Comment: this did it. before i tried this i tried doing a print_r() with $wishlistIsPublic and $itemCount(). basically, if the wishlist was private then it was null and not 0 as i expected. this is probably what you meant with "you cannot fetch an array with all rows and at the same time just a a single column from a single row separately" since i tried to fetch all and also 1 specific.

now $wishlistIsPublic correctly shows 1 or 0.

and i did: $pdo = $this->connect();

to avoid calling connect() multiple times.

Comment: i have a question if you dont mind me asking. i see you write "$stmt->execute([$userID]);" i personally prefer to write bindParam for itself and have an empty execute(). so i edited the first query to be "$stmt->bindParam(1, $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);" and also with bindColumn: "$stmt->bindColumn('wishlistIsPublic', $wishlistIsPublic, PDO::PARAM_INT);". i also changed the first fetch with "$results" instead of "$wishlistIsPublic" with fetchColumn(). it seems to have the exact same result. just wondering if there is a reason you didnt use bindColumn() and if you think this looks good enough.

Comment: If you don't mind writing twice or thrice more code than needed then you can use your favorite approach. there is no difference result-wise.